# How to configure multiple buttons/image buttons in single fragment?

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to link multiple image buttons all to different fragments from a single fragment.

For example

I want fragment 1 image button 1 to link to fragment 2, then I want fragment 1 image button 2 to link to fragment 3, finally I want fragment 1 image button 3 to link to fragment 4.

I have the first image button working, however I am unable to get more than 1 button working.

To be clear, I want a solution that does not require impementing onclicklistener into my fragment, as this makes it abstract and breaks my project.

I also do not want to use a listview fragment.

Any help would be really appreciated thanks.

Please see my code below

(Please note, I am looking for a way to make this applicable to multiple buttons i.e. something like else if or case R.id.xxxx

obviously I have looked around but had no luck anywhere

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import static android.R.attr.id;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        ImageButton c63button = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.c63button);
        c63button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mercedesamgroom mercedesamgroom = new mercedesamgroom();
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, mercedesamgroom)
                        .commit();




            }

        });

        return v;
    }

}
```